# I have stored few items in the form of multidimensional arrays in userdata and want to access them

Tags: codeigniter

Code below is basically what I did in actual. Here let's say I want to access an array at index 3 and 4th element of that same array:

```
<?php 

$data = array(  array('1','2','3'),
             '4', '5', 
         array('abc', 'klm','xyz'),
         array('1', '2', '88908', '3', '4')

        );
$this->session->set_userdata('data', $data);

print_r($this->session->userdata('data["5"]["4"]'));
?>
```

I want to access only `88908`.

Comment: What is the value of `$data`? Is that an array? also, You can set only one parameter on set_userdata. **EDIT:** Is `88908` is the user id?

Answer (score 1):

First, get full data:

```
      $data=$this->session->userdata('data');
```

Then access the array by key:

```
      $my_var=$data[4][2] ;  // returns 88908
```

You can use

```
    var_dump($data)
```

to see what is in the var.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing without storing into a variable you can use

`print_r($this->session->userdata('data')['4']['2']);`

Comment: Assuming there is not some casting to string going on in `set_userdata`, the numeric indices should be integers, not strings. They will be cast, so this would probably work, but it is a bit messy.